# Definition of an elliptic curve $E$ over $\Bbb{C}$ is defined over a subfield $⊆ℂ$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

An elliptic curve $E$ over $\Bbb{C}$) is defined over a subfield $⊆ℂ$

1. if $E$ is isomorphic(over $\Bbb{C}$ to $E_0$ whose coefficients are in $K$
2. if there exists an elliptic curve $E_0$ given by a Weierstrass equation with coefficients in  such that $E\cong E_0×_{K}{Spec(\Bbb{C})}$ as curves over $ \Bbb{C}$.

I encountered two above seemingly different definition.
Are these equivalent condition ? If so, what is the metric of bringing out fiber product-like definition ?

Comment: The second one should say $E_0\times_{\mathrm{Spec}(K)}\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)$. (It's also sometimes just denoted $E_0\times_K\mathbb C$, or even just $(E_0)_{\mathbb C}$.) It is just the scheme-theoretic way of saying the base change of $E_0$ to $\mathbb C$. So the second definition is just that there is a curve $E_0$ over $K$ that becomes isomorphic to $E$ over $\mathbb C$. The first definition is therefore equivalent.

Comment: What is the merit of scheme-theoretic discretion ? I want to hear your opinion or experiment.

Comment: In this case, it's just notation. The scheme theoretic viewpoint becomes helpful, for example, when you want to start thinking about integral models of $E$ (say over a number field), and talking about reduction to finite fields.